# Set-cookie Header doesn't set cookies to the browser

Tags: node.js, http, cookies, setcookie, httpcookie

I'm working on a full-stack web application based on React and Nodejs.
I deployed my front-end to the Nelify and backend to the heroku. It was working well at the local machine but there is an issue after deploying at the logging part. Except for logging, everything is working well. I guess res.cookie('w_auth',user.token) sends jwt tokens to the web browser but it's not set and it doesn't show any error message.

This is my back-end to send cookies to the browser

```
const cookieOpt = {
  maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000,
  domain: front-end domain,
  secure: true,
  sameSite: 'None',
}
 user.generateToken((err, user) => {
        if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);;
        res.cookie('w_authExp', user.tokenExp, cookieOpt);
        res.cookie('w_auth', user.token, cookieOpt).status(200).json({
          loginSuccess: true,
          userId: user._id,
        });
      });
```

front-end domain is the HTTPS nelify domain.

And this is the set-cookie in the header in the chrome dev tool.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1erAb.jpg)

Set-cookie header doesn't set cookies to the browser.
I can see alert icons but weirdly, it doesn't show any error message.

I tried to set the headers like
`// res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true); // res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:', front-domain);`
and give `httpOnly` option in the `cookieOpt`
but these doesn't work.
Is there anyone who has a clear idea for ironing out?